# How can I get jenkins-cli.jar to use my ssh agent/keychain?

Tags: jenkins, keychain, jenkins-cli, ssh-agent

I'm using the jenkins-cli.jar file from my jenkins server, and on every run it prompts me for my ssh key passphrase. I'd like it to use my ssh keychain so I don't have to enter it on every invocation.

If it matters, I'm on OSX using the default keychain setup, I don't have a manual ssh-agent configured right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jenkins CLI client does not support SSH agents for now.

As a workaround, you can generate dedicated key without passphrase, associate it with your Jenkins account and instruct client to use that key on every invocation.

Comment: And here is the bug tracking this issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45320 -- feel free to comment there.

Comment: Until now it was not improved, perhaps there is a special plugin that solved this?

Comment: @ManuelJordan, Jenkins CLI client (part of Jenkins core) needs to have the support for local SSH agent. Plugins cannot contribute such logic. They can implement alternative CLI client, though, but I am not aware of anyone that would.

Comment: @OliverGondža Thanks for the feedback, in the JIRA issue remains without solution. If the `" SSH-based CLI with regular SSH clients"` can be really improved to have the same set of features like the `java -jar`  approach would be excellent. I think I am going to create a JIRA issue about that.